# How to have blur edges?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

[image]

with the above node reference, i try to blur the edges. But not getting the same result.

**Below are my nodes**

[image]

Result - not having blur edges.

Any suggestion or help how to get the above result. Thanks

[image]

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file (only keep the useful objects)?

Comment: First of all: your _Transparent BSDF_ is plugged in the bottom socket of the _Mix Shader_, which would make the center of the plane transparent... but maybe that's what you want? The next thing is, your question lacks information: is this _Material Preview_ or _Rendered_ and are you using _Eevee_ or _Cycles_? Oh, and one thing I forgot: you are using the _Object_ texture coordinates for the _Gradient Texture_. I cannot see the origin of the plane, is it in the center of the mesh?